# Hive Warehouse Connector + Spark = signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, hdp

I'm trying to use `hive warehouse connector` and `spark` on `hdp 3.1` and getting exception even with simplest example (below). 
The class causing problems: `JaninoRuntimeException` - is in `org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.8` (dependency of spark_sql) and in `com.hortonworks.hive:hive-warehouse-connector_2.11:jar`.

I've tried to exclude janino library from spark_sql, but this resulted in missing other classes from janino. And I need hwc to for the new functionality.

Anyone had same error? Any ideas how to deal with it?

I'm getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:1321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3277)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:15)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
    ... 5 more
```

my sbt file:

```
name := "testHwc"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

resolvers += "Hortonworks repo" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hortonworks.hive/hive-warehouse-connector
libraryDependencies += "com.hortonworks.hive" %% "hive-warehouse-connector" % "1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78"
```

And the source code:

```
import com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val ss = SparkSession.builder()
      .config("spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url", "nnn")
      .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import ss.sqlContext.implicits._

    val rdd = ss.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

    rdd.toDF("col1").show()
    val hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(ss).build()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I've discovered that the presence of error depends on the order of libraries in `classpath`.

For unknown reason when I was running this project in IntelliJ IDEA the classpath was always with random order and the app was failing and succeeding randomly.

In the end - `HiveWarehouseConnector` jar in `classpath` should be **after** `Spark Sql` jar.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479541/intellij-idea-editor-classpath-order) answer - the order inside IntelliJ IDEA can be changed in dependencies tab.

Otherwise - I was not able to solve this issue for IntelliJ - the order was always random, but when i executed program outside of IntelliJ - I set the order I needed.

Comment: Hey, Can you share more information? How did you supply order runtime?

Answer (score 0):

In maven projects, I solve it like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
           <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).